# Apollo monorepo - WS connection

Tags: heroku, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I'm working on an Apollo Graphql real time app which is deployed to Heroku and contains both client and server files in the same project (the server is serving the create-react-app build files).

I'm trying to open a websocket connection between the client and the server and I can't figure out how to do so.

I tried to set the ws uri in the client to "wss://" but apollo returns an error which is saying that it's not a valid uri.

Previously I had two different projects (client / server) on heroku and I set in the uri the path to the server app and it's worked properly.

Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Comment: define server url ... as usual ... of course

Comment: I explicitly defined the server url also and it didn't work either